# Transpose particular columns into rows based on a particular column in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry for the tongue twister question. I came across a below situation and need a desired out as mentioned below too. I'm completely new to Excel world.

Here unique identifier is c1,f1 and i1 respectively.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF2Gi.jpg

Existing

```
a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  c1
d1  d2  d3  e1  e2  f1
g1  g2  g3  h1  h2  i1
```

Desired

```
a1  a2  a3  b1  c1
a1  a2  a3  b2  c1
d1  d2  d3  e1  f1
d1  d2  d3  e2  f1
g1  g2  g3  h1  i1
g1  g2  g3  h2  i1
```

Comment: Do you just want to copy each set of data in this exact way (as in described in "Desired output")?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF2Gi.jpg

Comment: Does it follow any specific system, or do you just have a random, fixed pattern for copying those values?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the original data in columns A to F and you want the output in columns H to L put the following formula in Cell H1

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2),COLUMN(A:A)-1)
```

Copy this across to columns H:L and copy down as far as you need to go.

Then modify the formula in Cell K1 to:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2),MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+COLUMN(D:D)-1)
```

And copy this down as far as you need to go.

[image: Output]

The formulas in the output cells will work if they are moved but the $A$1 bit is important.